# Remove Quicktime from Firefox

Tags: firefox, plugins, quicktime

No matter what I try, the Quicktime plugin in Firefox on Vista will not go away. I have deleted all of the plugin files in "Mozilla Firefox/plugins" as well as unistalling the program itself and deleting the junk still left behind in Program Files.

After all that, somehow Quicktime still runs its plugin in Firefox. How can I disable it?

I've installed QT Lite as the alternative, but it doesn't seem to install a plugin in Firefox, even though I have the option checked.

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, the VLC plugin (optionally installed on VLC installation) should be able to play most QT movies, if you're after that functionality without dealing with anything QT-branded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How to Remove a Quicktime Plugin on Firefox**

- Click on the "Tools" menu in Firefox and select "Add-ons" to temporarily disable the QuickTime plugin without fully uninstalling it. Select "QuickTime Plugin." Click the button to the right of the selection labeled "Disable." The plugin can be enabled with another click.
- Type "about:config" in the browser's location bar and hit "Enter" to manually remove the Quicktime plugin from within Firefox. Depending on your system's configuration, a button may pop up that reads "I'll be careful, I promise!" Click the button to confirm.
- Search for or scroll down to "plugin.expose_full_path." Double-click on the value "false" to the right of "plugin.expose_full_path" to change it to "true."
- Type "about:plugins" in the browser's location bar and hit "Enter." Scroll down the list to QuickTime. There will likely be several QuitckTime plugins listed.
- Note the file listed next to each QuickTime plugin on the list. For example, the listing may be "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\plugins\npqtplugin2.dll."
- Navigate in Windows Explorer to each of the QuickTime plugin files you noted in Step 5. Delete or change each file name. For example, you can change "npqtplugin2.dll" to "XXnpqtplugin2.dll."
- Close the Explorer or Finder windows and restart Firefox. The QuickTime plugin should now be uninstalled.

[Source](http://www.ehow.com/how_5077179_remove-quicktime-plugin-firefox.html)

only if Quicktime has been thoroughly removed yo may be able to use QTA or QTL as a browser plugin.

Comment: @Molly: He says he did delete all of them and QT itself. Strange.

Comment: Aha! It looks like a plugin I must have installed for some arbitrary reason (3dvia) was hiding Quicktime with it in "Program Files/Virtools". Quicktime is finally killed! Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... well quicktime is gone, but QT Lite actually seems to reinstall the npqtplugin's back into Firefox, and Quicktime is back.

Comment: Oh wait, I'm betting that's what QT is... haha, Fail. I assumed it would have at least a custom icon and menu when right clicking on .mov's.

Comment: Fail is right, i don't even bother with installing this plugin, no matter how tempting the content might be :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've deleted :

1. The quicktime the plugins from `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\plugins\`:
   npqtplugin.dll, npqtplugin2.dll, etc.
2. The folder "C:\Program Files\Quicktime\"

There is no way that Quicktime can still run.

Comment: It's the strangest thing. It's all deleted, but somehow it still runs fine, and is listed in the Firefox plugin menu.

Comment: What do you mean by "runs fine"? Does it launch an external program?

Comment: No, it's embedded.

Answer (score 0):

This solution removes the QuickTime player from the system including firefox. It does not remove the codecs and other required files for playing QuickTime files. If you are using QuickTime Player outside firefox then this solution is not for you.

Most preferably do this with firefox closed.

1. Go to Control Panel and find "programs and features".
2. Find QuickTime and then press the button "Change" on top of the list
3. From the QuickTime installation window select "Modify"
4. Then go to QuickTime Player and press the button on the left and select "Entire feature will be unavailable"
5. Press change and in a few seconds you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

But you don't NEED QuickTime for anything. Just uninstall it, then install a good adware-free media player like VLC Media Player or Daum PotPlayer. The next time Firefox wants to open a media file usually associated with QuickTime (.mov, mp4, etc.), click "Open With..." and select your media player, and FF will run the player externally and open the media file in it. It'll then remember your choice for next time.

Comment: Some video editing software depends on a quicktime installation. I'm not a fan of the fact, but so it is.